# getting the output of two lists using for loop

Tags: python, comparison

I would greatly appreciate, if you guys could help me with this query.

In my python code, I have opened two files using the open(file, r) function.

Now what I want is, read all the lines of these two files and compare two columns in those data if they match.

I have tried a nested for loop for each line in files

```
for line in file:
  for lines in file:
     file1 = split(line)
     file2 = split(lines)
     process matching query
```

However, it does not seem to be working. 
Could you guys point me in the right direction on how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through those files simultaneously with [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for line1,line2 in zip(file1,file2):
```

And do all the logic with the lines.

For Python 3.x `zip` is an iterator, and in Python 2.x you can use [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) with the same functionality. Using `zip` in Python 2.x. will lead to reading all the file contents into memory, while iterator version will advance line by line.

Comment: Hi ovgolovin, thanks for the swift reply. I always assumed that with zip, the list contents had to be the same length. THe two lists that I have are not in the same length, in fact, they contain different data apart from one column where they share the same data (hence the matching).

Comment: @user1743872 Inside the `for` loop split each line, extract the needed  column and compare. `zip(file1,file2)` only allows to advance through files' lines simultaneously.

Comment: Hello ovgolovin, do you mean the for loop in my initial post or the for loop that you posted. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1743872 I mean for-loop in my answer. In your answer for each line of the first loop you go through all the lines of the second file in the nested loop.

Comment: @user1743872 There is a possibility that I didn't get you question right. It would be better if you proved the example of `file1` and `file2` content and what you want to achieve.

Comment: basically,  I want to go through to files at once, make their contents as 2 separate lists and then do some matching.